# Phase Separation Question

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

My question is based on the following diagram:

[image]

Basically, I understand that any mixture that is between x1' and x2'' will separate into those two phases.

However, why is that a mixture > x2'' or < x2'' cannot do the same thing? That is, split into a mixture of two phases, one with x2'' and one with x2'

Or can someone explain fundamentally how the mixture is able to split like the diagram shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider the case $x_2'<x_2<x_2''$. The free energy of an homogeneous mixture is $G(x_2)$.

Imagine now that the mixture undergoes a phase separation. A fraction $\rho$ ($0\le\rho\le 1$) is in the phase of concentration $x_2''$ while a fraction $1-\rho$ is in the phase of concentration $x_2'$. $\rho$ is chosen such that
      $$x_2=(1-\rho)x_2'+\rho x_2''\ \Leftrightarrow\ 
  \rho={x_2-x_2'\over x_2''-x_2'}$$
in order to impose the conservation of the total mass of each one of the two components of the mixture. The total free energy is now
      $$G=\rho G(x_2')+(1-\rho)G(x_2'')$$
which is the equation of the dashed line on your curve. Obviously, the free energy $G$ is lower than $G(x_2)$, i.e. the free energy of the homogeneous mixture.

In the cases $x_2>x_2''$ and $x_2<x_2'$, the phase separation cannot be undergone because the first equation ($x_2=(1-\rho) x_2'+\rho x_2''$) has no physical solutions. Indeed, for $x_2>x_2''$, the solution is $\rho>1$ while
for $x_2<x_2'$, $\rho<0$.